# check if element is empty in C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I have this to enter data into an input field in a form:

```
Driver_.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@aria-labelledby='i1']")).SendKeys("text to enter");
```

it works fine, but I need to check if the field is empty first
I have tried:

```
string Result = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@aria-labelledby='i1']")).Text;
```

but the var `Result` returns blank when the field contains text.
I am trying to read the text in the field and act accordingly, with

```
string Result = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@aria-labelledby='i1']")).Text;
```

But returns blank.
`.Tagname` returns "input"
`.Enabled` returns "True"
`.Text`    returns ""

The HTML:

```html
<input type="text" class="quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput exportInput" jsname="YPqjbf" autocomplete="off" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="i1" aria-describedby="i2 i3" dir="auto" data-initial-dir="auto" data-initial-value="this is text I put in the field" badinput="false">
```

Comment: Please take the time to format your question appropriately so it's readable, and to tag your question with the appropriate libraries you're using. Both of these things will increase your chance of receiving a valid answer.

Comment: `input` elements don't have text content, they have a `value` attribute though...

Comment: Thanks Heretic Monkey 9 but its a form and it as text in it once the user as input it the element in the inspect window after text is inserted is;
<input type="text" class="quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput exportInput" jsname="YPqjbf" autocomplete="off" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="i1" aria-describedby="i2 i3" dir="auto" data-initial-dir="auto" data-initial-value="this is text I put in the field" badinput="false">
if that helps

Comment: What HereticMonkey means is that the element you are querying does not have a text property, it has a value property, so if you want the text that was entered you must query the value property, not the (nonexistent) text property.

Comment: I added the HTML in your comment to you question. In the future, please do not put code in comments. It is too difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

Form input fields have a `value` property, which stores the text that was entered by the user. You need to get the value property using Selenium:

```
var input = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@aria-labelledby='i1']"));

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input.GetProperty("value")))
{
    input.SendKeys("text to enter");
}
```

Note that the `value` HTML attribute and `value` Document Object Model property are different things. The `value` HTML attribute usually retains the same text as when the page first loaded, but the `value` **DOM property** changes when the user enters or changes the text in the form field.